# It is possible the array changes its elements without any reason? - Fortran 77

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran77

I am quite new in fortran, so maybe this could be a silly question.

I have a problem with an array that seems to change its elements without any reason. I have just plotted the array and you can see that it shouldn't change but apparently it does:

[image]

The code is quite long, I paste just the part regarding the array. Basically from the main code I call a soubroutine that does some calculations on the element 'kkk' which is a grain. If the axis of the grains are below a certain amount, the grain is set to dead and stored in this array called DEADGR that is the array that changes the elements.

```
 c     TOTAL COUNTER OF DEAD GRAINS

       NDEADGRTOTAL=0

 C     SET TO 0 THE COUNTER OF DEAD GRAINS IN STEP
       NDEADGR=0
       NDEADGRTOTALOLD=NDEADGRTOTAL

       DO NN=1,NLIVEGR
           KKK=LIVEGR(NN)
           CALL GROWTH(KKK,IDEAD)
  C      IF THE GRAIN HAS TO BE ELIMINATED STORE IN ARRAY DEADGRAINS

        IF (IDEAD.EQ.1) THEN
              NDEADGR=NDEADGR+1 !DEAD GRAINS IS STEP
              NDEADGRTOTAL=NDEADGRTOTAL+1 !TOTAL DEAD GRAINS
              DEADGR(NDEADGRTOTAL)=KKK !STORE THE ID OF THE DEAD GRAIN
        END IF            
  END DO
```

This is the subroutine:

```
  SUBROUTINE GROWTH(KKK,IDEAD)

  INCLUDE 'vpsc7.dim'

  REAL RO, GRV, DELTAX, NEWVOL, DUMMYONE, OLDVOL, toll
  integer idead

  toll=1e-5

C     GET VARIABLES USED IN THE ROUTINE
  RO=DSLDNSTY(KKK)
  OLDVOL=VOL(KKK)

  IDEAD=0

C     CALCULATE GRAIN BOUNDARY VELOCITY
  GRV=MOB*0.5*MU*BURG*BURG*(AVGDSLDNSTY-RO)
  DELTAX=2*GRV*TINCR      !VARIATION IN LENGHT OF AXES

C     GET ACTUAL AXES LENGHT OF GRAIN KKK      
  AX1GR=AXISGR(0,1,KKK)
  AX2GR=AXISGR(0,2,KKK)
  AX3GR=AXISGR(0,3,KKK)

C     UPDATE AXES
  AX1GR=AX1GR+DELTAX
  AX2GR=AX2GR+DELTAX
  AX3GR=AX3GR+DELTAX

C     IF ONE OF THE AXIS IS NEGATIVE THE GRAIN IS SET TO DEAD
  if ((AX1GR.LE.toll).OR.(AX2GR.LE.toll).OR.(AX3GR.LE.toll)) then
        IDEAD=1
        RETURN
  end if

C     CALCULATE NEW VOLUME
  NEWVOL=(4./3.)*PI*AX1GR*AX2GR*AX3GR

C     CALCULATE THE GROWTH FACTOR
  DUMMYONE=NEWVOL/OLDVOL

C     ASSIGN VARIABLES BEFORE EXIT FROM SUBROUTINE
  VOLGRGROWTH(KKK)=NEWVOL
  GRGRWTHFAC(KKK)=DUMMYONE


  RETURN
  END
```

I use the Intel Parallel Studio XE 2015.

Comment: No, arrays don't change by themselves. Most probably you access some array out of bounds. Enable all runtime checks your compiler (which you do not name) has. For example `gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall -fbacktrace  `.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What this runtime check does? The compiler is Intel Parallel Studio XE2015, I have just edited the question. Thanks

Comment: For intel use `-g -check -warn -traceback` in Linux or an equivalent if you use Windows. This will enable checking if you are accessing the arrays properly. If that does not help,  prepare a small example (by deleting unrelated parts of your code), which is small enough to show it here completely, but still exhibits the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, using your suggestion about the runtime checks, I discovered the debugging inside Visual Studio which is much better than the one from command. In Visual studio I can see all the arrays without printing one by one. I am sure I will find where my mistake is now, but if I don't I will do as you said. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can do it as you wish, but be sure to compile in the Debug mode and not in the Release mode. https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/595689

Comment: If you're trying to track down this specific bug, I recommend you use runtime bounds checking and *not* complete 'print everything' debugging. It is possible to have too much information.